# Two datepickers using fxml

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm building a library loan system GUI,using javafx & fxml. I have two datepickers, loan/start Date(fromDate) and return/end Date(toDate), which indicates the timeline a book will be loaned.

What I'm trying to do is;

fromDate can be set as any date after current date. (including date today)

toDate can be set as any date after fromDate.

so the date loaned cannot start in a date before today, and date to return the book is after it's start date.

Here's my code :

LibraryController.java

```
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    fromDate.setValue(LocalDate.now());
    toDate.setValue(fromDate.getValue().plusDays(1));

    Callback<DatePicker, DateCell> dayCellFactory = fromDate -> new DateCell()
    {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty)
        {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if(item.isBefore(LocalDate.now()))
            {
                setDisable(true);
                setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ffc0cb;");


            }
        }
    };

    Callback<DatePicker, DateCell> dayCellFactory2 = toDate -> new DateCell()
    {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty)
        {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if(item.isBefore(fromDate.getValue().plusDays(1)))
            {
                setDisable(true);
                setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ffc0cb;");


            }
        }
    };

    fromDate.setDayCellFactory(dayCellFactory);
    toDate.setDayCellFactory(dayCellFactory2);
}
```

LibraryLoanManagementMain.fxml

```
<AnchorPane>
<GridPane>
    <children>
        <DatePicker fx:id="fromDate" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="180.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
        <DatePicker fx:id="toDate" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="180.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
    </children>
</GridPane>
</AnchorPane>
```

Root layout is then loaded from fxml file in the main method.

When I remove dayCellFactory2, the code works fine. The GUI works with dayCellFactory2, but throws many number of errors.Exception thrown is

```
 Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The problem is with `toDate`and dayCellFactory2. How can I fix the errors and make it work accordingly,disabling it's dates before the selected value of `fromDate`?

Comment: This works fine for me. Can you create a [MCVE] and [edit] your question to include it?

Comment: I'll check and edit,thank you

Comment: Cells need to deal with the case where the cell is empty/the `item` is `null` too...